# Asynchronous processing of data in Expressjs

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, async.js

I've an Express route which receives some data and process it, then insert into mongo (using mongoose).

This is working well if I return a response after the following steps are done:

- Receive request
- Process the request data
- Insert the processed data into Mongo
- Return 204 response

But client will be calling this API concurrently for millions of records. Hence the requirement is not to block the client for processing the data. Hence I made a small change in the code:

- Receive request
- Return response immediately with 204
- Process the requested data
- Insert the processed data into Mongo

The above is working fine for the first few requests (say 1000s), after that client is getting `socket exception: connection reset peer` error. I guess it is because server is blocking the connection as the port is not free and at some point of time, I notice my nodejs process is throwing out `Out of memory` error.

Sample code is as follows:

```js
async function enqueue(data) {
    // 1. Process the data
    // 2. Insert the data in mongo
}

async function expressController(request, response) {
    logger.info('received request')
    response.status(204).send()

    try {
        await enqueue(request.body)
    } catch (err) {
        throw new Error(err)
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: How many records do you send to server per request? How sending request to server blocks the client for processing the data??

Comment: In a single request there could be 500 records

Comment: Did you check [this](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/6206) issue?

Comment: Since you mentioned that the data is immense, you should reconsider your architecture. I am not sure what you are using for the architecture, but the best solution would be using the AWS SQS Queue. Add the elements in a queue and make a separate lambda which process the elements(insert it into db). This lambda would get trigger when the elements are added into the queue. This way it would scale up as much as you want and no blocks or latency. Your controller would just add the items into the queue only.

Comment: Yeah definitely adding a queue is one way that I'm looking at (not using any cloud services). I'll wait to see if anyone has. other approaches without involving a queue. Thanks @HassanAbbas

Comment: @Saeed: Yes, for this use case, I've increased the connection pool from 5 (default) to 20, even 40 also. But that didn't help much. Because the database calls are executed once the request connections are drained out. Till the db insertion happens, it is keeping all the request body in memory and thus the out of memory happening.